# Why the app crashed when using KVO for observe in page view controller ? and How to make the KVO to be effected?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, key-value-observing, uicontainerview

I'm trying to use KVO to observe the update change when using drag in my page view controller's child content view controller's scrollView, but when the app launch, it crashed says:

**"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7ff003d3f5b0 of class KVOPageVC.ContentViewController was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it."**

Here below is my code and screenshot:

**APP SCREENSHOT**
[image]

**CODE**

> PageViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

var pageLabels: Array<String> = ["First Page", "Second Page", "Third Page"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = self

    self.setViewControllers([contentViewForPage(0)], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func contentViewForPage(index: Int) -> ContentViewController {
    let contentVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentVC") as! ContentViewController

    contentVC.pageIndex = index
    contentVC.label = pageLabels[index]

    return contentVC
}
}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if index == 0 || index == NSNotFound {
        return nil
    }

    index -= 1

    return contentViewForPage(index)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if index == NSNotFound {
        return nil
    }

    index += 1

    if index == self.pageLabels.count {
        return nil
    }

    return contentViewForPage(index)
}


}
```

> ObeserverViewController.swift

**it's 'a view controller' embedded in 'content view controller's' 'Container View', when the user drag and release the scroll below, i want the emoji face to be replaced by the text "to be notified!"**

```
import UIKit

class ObeserverViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var notifyLabel: UILabel!// when the user drag the scroll view and release, i hope its value will be changed accordingly.

var contentVC: ContentViewController! //the variable to hold the object

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.contentVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentVC")
    self.contentVC.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "changingLabel", options: [], context: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.contentVC.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "changingLabel")
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "changingLabel" {
        notifyLabel.text = "to be notified!"
    }
}

deinit {
    self.contentVC.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "changingLabel")
}

}
```

> ContentViewController.swift

**Page view controller's child view controllers, 3 pages in total. It includes a Scroll View and a Container View(embedded ObeserverViewController)**

```
import UIKit

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

var label: String!
var pageIndex: Int!

dynamic var changingLabel: String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    contentLabel.text = label
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}

}

extension ContentViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -50 {
        if contentView.backgroundColor == UIColor.greenColor() {
            contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            self.setValue("hah", forKey: "changingLabel")
        } else {
            contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            self.setValue("wow", forKey: "changingLabel")
        }
    }
}
}
```

> My questions is:

**How can i make the emoji label text to be notified to change in one controller when i drag and release the scroll view in another controller?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are adding observer to one object and removing from another. When you are calling `instanciateViewController...` it will create you new object of passed view controller identifier. Than you are signing to it's changes via KVO. But in `viewWillDissapear` you are not getting the same object that was crated in `viewWillAppear`, but crating new one(it has nothing with that was created in `viewWillAppear`). Than you are resigning from it's notification, still as it is not the same object that you has created previously and signed to him(with KVO), such resigning won't lead to needed result. What you need to do is to save firstly created object to some variable and than resign this variable where it's needed.

Secondly you need to remove observer not only in `viewWillDissapear` method but as well in

```
deinit {
    // perform the deinitialization
}
```

Than you will be sure that if your object is deleted than it as well will be resigned from notifications.

Your error message tells that object that was signed for notifications was marked as deleted, still it was not signed out and it will be receiving notification even if it's deleted(sound not really good as memory that he belongs to may already be used for some other objects, that may lead to undefined behavior of your app).

Comment: Thank you very much @Volodymyr. I revised the code as you suggested, the app does not crash now. Then I create a variable `contentVC` to hold the object, and try using `self.contentVC` to refer the same object. But the KVO is still not work! When i drag and release the scroll view, emoji face still there, not changed to `to be notified!` as expected. I think the problem remains the same as you mentioned Firstly, that the object registers for KVO is not the object to be notified, right? I'v no idea to make sure the same object is used. It's very appreciate if you may give some detail advice!

Comment: There may be a lot of reasons. I can't help without access to full code.

Comment: Please download the full code from my dropbox "https://db.tt/FYagntBp".